# Loop through multiple textboxes Code igniter php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form in my view page where there have two select boxes and three input boxes in a row .I put them in a for loop and make five rows in which every row there is two select box and 3 simple text boxes .I write a function in **jquery** where if i select value from one select box it will appear in 2nd select box .But after making five rows in a loop ,this function is working only in the first row not other four rows . I don't know how to do that .If any one can code it for me,then thanks to him ...

This is my view page

```
   <tr>
 <th>Category:</th>
   <th>Items:</th>
   <th>Selling Price:</th>
    <th>quantity:</th>
   <th> total:</th>
</tr>

<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    ?>
    <tr>
           <td>     


    <?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id', $records2, '#', 'id="category"');?>
    </td>
   <td>                 

    <?php echo form_dropdown('item_id', $records3, '#', 'id="items"'); ?>

     </td>           

    <td><?php echo form_input($price); ?> </td>

       <td><?php echo form_input($quantity); ?></td>

       <td> <?php echo form_input($total); ?>
        </td></tr>

     <?php }?></table>
```

My **JavaScript** for two select boxes.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){  
      $('#check').click(function(){
     alert("hello");
     return false;
 });
      $('#category').change(function(){ 
    $("#items > option").remove();
    var category_id = $('#category').val();  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "stockInController/get_Items/"+category_id, 

        success: function(items) //we're calling the response json array 'cities'
        {
            $.each(items,function(item_id,item_name) 
            {
                var opt = $('<option />'); 
                opt.val(item_id);
                opt.text(item_name);
                $('#items').append(opt);
            });
        }

    });

 });
  });
```

**JavaScript** for sending values to the controller

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $('#btn').click(function() { //  $("#form").serialize()

var cust_id = $('#cust_id').val();
var item_id = $('#items').val();


var sales_date = $('#sales_date').val();
var sales_bill_no = $('#sales_bill_no').val();
var price = $('#price').val();
var quantity = $('#quantity').val();




var form_data = {
        cust_id: $('#cust_id').val(),
        sales_date: $('#sales_date').val(),
        sales_bill_no: $('#sales_bill_no').val(),
        price: $('#price').val(),
        quantity: $('#quantity').val(),
        item_id: $('#items').val(),




};


$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo site_url('salesController/addSales'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form_data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg) {
        if(msg.res == 1)
        {
            $(".success").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
            alert("true");
        }
        else{
            alert("false");          
          }


    }
});

return false;
   });


  </script>
```

i have done this but this not working

```
 <?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id', $records2, '#', "id='category_".$i."'");?>

  <?php echo form_dropdown('item_id', $records3, '#', "id='items_".$i."'"); ?>



        <script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function()
    {  
     for (var i= 0; i<5; i++)
          {
    $('#category_'+ i).change(function(){




        $('#items_'+ i > option").remove(); 
        var category_id = $('#category_'+ i).val(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "stockInController/get_Items/"+category_id, 

            success: function(items)
            {
                $.each(items,function(item_id,item_name) 
                {
                    var opt = $('<option />'); 
                    opt.val(item_id);
                    opt.text(item_name);
                    $('#items_'+ i).append(opt); 
                });
            }

        });

    });
}

    });
```

Comment: 1)Never use words like " _code for me_ ".. We are here to guide.. Not to code..

Comment: 2)You are using same ids in all 5 rows... I mean `category` & `items`.. So your code doesn't work.. Use unique ids like `category1,category2..category5`

Comment: how can i give them a diffrnt id as they are in a looop

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that in each row you have to inputs that have ID's "category" and "items". Each element on the page should have a unique ID. Maybe for row 1 they are "cat_1" and "item_1" or something similar. 
Right now it is kind of like you have a room with 10 people, 5 named Johnny and 5 named Sarah. If you walk in and ask for Johnny, you will have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
?>
<tr>
       <td>     


<?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id', $records2, '#', "id='category".$i."'");?>
</td>
```

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('item_id', $records3, '#', "id='items".$i."'"); ?>

 </td>
```

Similarly,run a loop in your javascript and get the values of categories and items

EDIT:

```
for(i=0;i < 5; i++){
$("#category"+i).change(function(){ 
$("#items"+i+" > option").remove();
var category_id = $("#category"+i).val();  
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "stockInController/get_Items/"+category_id, 

    success: function(items) //we're calling the response json array 'cities'
    {
        $.each(items,function(item_id,item_name) 
        {
            var opt = $('<option />'); 
            opt.val(item_id);
            opt.text(item_name);
            $("#items"+i).append(opt);
        });
    }

});
}
```

Comment: rikka ok thanks .. now how to know i loop in jquery .. because at now its not working ... i have to loop through i think jquery as well ?

Comment: its not working ..i think u r trying to use php in  javascript ?

Comment: @user1972143 That's not php.. for loop will work in js.. And didn't give you the complete code.. Just loop all the cases in which u've used `categories` and `items`..

Comment: rikka ..check my updated question .. i have done this the same as you said .. but not working

Comment: @user1972143 You haven't kept `_` for items in your jquery

Comment: @user1972143 You got to be missing something.. Check whether you've used repeating ids somewhere else.. And also check the ids of the dropdowns using firebug whether they are unique or not..

Comment: ..thanks for your help and time .. it is not working buddy .. dont know whats going on .. i checked through firebug in which in respose tab .. :false: is displaying  and above the link says that .localhost/....../get_items/undefined